# Python typing append string to class members

Tags: python, python-typing, typeddict

Suppose I have a type-hinted class like so:

```
class Foo:
  one: str
  two: int
  three: str
```

Is it possible to declare a type such that it has the same attributes as `Foo` but with e.g. `_a` appended to the end that is visible to the static type checker? i.e.

```
class Bar:
  one_a: str
  two_a: int
  three_a: str
```

In other words, I'd like to declare `Foo` alone and then automatically generate the type `Bar` so that any variable of type `Bar` would have `one_a` etc. appear during code-completion. Coming from a TypeScript background this would be pretty straightforward to implement but I'm not sure Python's type system is expressive enough.

Comment: No, there is no automatic way to do this in python. Out of curiosity, how would this be handled in Typescript? Note, Python uses nominal typing (with some support for structural typing), so generally not like Typescript.

Comment: Yes, I feared this was the case. I guess I'll have to define `Bar` manually and write some tests to ensure the `Foo` and `Bar` declerations are always kept up to date during any code changes. Regarding TypeScript, it's a new-ish feature but check out https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as

Comment: You could probable define a metaclass that did something like this.

Comment: @martineau do you any example code of how would that work?

Comment: Do you want to define ``Bar`` just as a runtime type, or also as a static type?

Comment: A static type. In fact in my use-case no object will ever have to actually have type Bar, it's purely for static type-checking and code-completion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will make them appear during code-completion like you want because that depends on how smart your IDE is, but here's how a metaclass could be used to add the desired type-hinting annotations to the other class:

```
class MyMetaClass(type):
    """ Create class that with annotations from a template class whose
        name have all had a suffix added to them.
    """
    def __new__(metaclass, classname, bases, classdict):

        _template = classdict.get('_template', None)
        _suffix = classdict.get('_suffix', None)

        if not (_template and _suffix):
            raise RuntimeError(f'_template or _suffix not defined in class {classname!r}')

        __annotations__ = {name+_suffix: type
                                for name, type in _template.__annotations__.items()}
        classdict['__annotations__'] = __annotations__

        return type.__new__(metaclass, classname, bases, classdict)


class Foo:
    one: str
    two: int
    three: str


class Bar(metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    _template = Foo
    _suffix = '_a'


print(f'{Bar.__annotations__}')  # -> {'one_a': <class 'str'>, 'two_a': <class 'int'>, 'three_a': <class 'str'>}
```